# php combine 2 arrays in a single one

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays as below :

```
array1:
1 => andrew
2 => Colin
...

and 
array2:
1 => Helen
2 => Angela
....
```

I would like to know how can I combine them to result something like andrew => Helen . I tried array_intersect_key($arrat1, array_fill_keys($arrat2, NULL)); but unfortunately it doesn't work due the fact I have php 5.1 and this requires php 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), passing your first array as the array of keys, and your second array as the array of values:

```
$combined = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Note that your arrays must have both equal length or the function won't work.

Comment: This should work - if you actually do have those numeric indices, it might not - but in that instance, you can do: $combined = array_combine(array_values($array1), array_values($array2));

Comment: @Stephen Orr: `array_combine()` ignores indexes, to maintain the order you need to sort the input arrays accordingly.

Comment: I didn't realise that! I've used `array_combine()` a fair bit but never come across that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
   $new_array[$v] = $array2[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function `array_merge()`?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a foreach loop :

```
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $id => $v) {
  $result[$v] = $array2[$id];
}
```